# Can ithreads be used with Moose lazy attributes?

Tags: multithreading, perl, moose

For the below program I'm getting this error message:

> Thread 2 terminated abnormally: Invalid value for shared scalar at
>   reader Foo::bar (defined at ... line 9) line 10.

The program consists of a pipeline where the first thread creates some Moose-based objects and puts them in the queue, which are then picked up in the second thread. The problem seems to be that the attribute is lazy because the error disappears if I remove the lazy setting.

```
package Foo;
use Moose;

has 'bar' => (
    is      => 'ro',
    isa     => 'HashRef', # the error doesn't happen with simpler datatypes
    lazy    => 1, # this line causes the error
    default => sub { return { map {$_ => $_} (1 .. 10) } },
);

package main;

use threads;
use Thread::Queue;

my $threadq = Thread::Queue->new;

sub create {
    # $_ doesn't seem to be thread-safe
    # this resolved another problem I had with a custom Moose type constraint 
    # where the 'where' clause used $_
    local $_;

    $threadq->enqueue( Foo->new ) foreach 1 .. 5;
    $threadq->enqueue( undef );
    return;
}

sub process {
    local $_;
    while (my $f = $threadq->dequeue) {
        print keys %{$f->bar}, "\n";
    }
    return;
}

threads->create( \&create )->join;
threads->create( \&process )->join;
```

Can anyone shed some light on this problem? Is Moose itself thread-safe (I couldn't find much in the documentation about this)?

Comment: Well at the very least CPAN Testers shows pass results for the Moose test suite with threaded perls http://www.cpantesters.org/distro/M/Moose.html#Moose-2.0401 though I'm not sure anything in the test suite exercises threads.

Comment: Perl probably isn't copying the code reference in `default` to the new thread.

Comment: @BradGilbert yes perhaps, although the same error also happens if I change `default` to a `builder` which I wouldn't expect to have issues with coderef copying

Comment: @Brad Gilbert, I don't think the code reference is in the *object*. It's in the *class*. The code reference would have been copied already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thread::Queue replaces all the hashes and arrays in your object with shared hashes and arrays with the same content, and does so recursively.

At the same time, you are attempting to change the object. Yeah, that's not gonna end well. (And not because of any bug in Moose, Thread::Queue or threads.)

A solution is to pass around the object in a serialised form. You could handle serialisation and deserialisation yourself, or you could use [Thread::Queue::Any](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Thread%3a%3aQueue%3a%3aAny) to have it done implicitly.

```
use threads;
use Thread::Queue::Any;

my $threadq = Thread::Queue::Any->new;

sub create {
    $threadq->enqueue( Foo->new ) for 1 .. 5;
    $threadq->enqueue( );
}

sub process {
    while ( my ($f) = $threadq->dequeue ) {
       print sort keys %{$f->bar};
       print "\n";
    }
}
```

Note there are subtle but important differences in the usage of `enqueue` and `dequeue`. Most importantly, `dequeue` must be called in list context when using T::Q::A. This is because `enqueue`'s argument list is passed as one message, and `dequeue` returns that argument list.